# How to batch join a sequence of images with a sequence of alphas?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

What I have:

- [A] a sequence of RGB images
- [B] a sequence of grayscale alpha images (but also in RGB)

What I want:

- a sequence of RGBA images that have untouched RGB channels from the [A] sequence, and the alpha channel created from the [B] sequence.

Is there a way to do this using Blender's sequence editor?

---

EDIT: I'm almost there. The trick is to load both sequences as Movie Clips, add these to the compositor using the Movie Clip node, and combine channels.

The remaining problem is the way the alpha is handled - I want straight all the way (so that the RGB channels are not touched), but I can't find any settings for that, and I get a white outline, such as often appears when there is straight/premultiplied alpha mismatch:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jvf9r7fu6j9hrna/shot_170905_203012.png

Comment: You can use *SetAlpha* node in the compositor to join both sequences, if that's acceptable...?

Comment: @brockmann Almost - see the edited question.

Comment: The method used in that screenshot is wrong. Try with the SetAlpha node instead, as @brockmann suggested.

Comment: Where does the source material come from? (I mean, do you know what program was used to produce it?)

Comment: I agree with troy_s regarding associated (premultiplied) alpha is your best bet here.
Use the SetAlpha node, then plug an AlphaConvert from straight to premul.
That will result in a correct associated image. Blender wil pre-divide it back if you save the output as PNG.

Comment: The images came from AfterEffects - the source shouldn't matter though, right?

Comment: SetAlpha + AlphaConvert removes the outline, but I also lose the padding from the RGB channels - I need those to make some manual fixes to the alpha later: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4b5cz4gkjrt8mox/shot_170905_210901.png

Comment: Well, it does: After Effect has an unassociated alpha internal workflow, while Blender and most of the nodal compositors have a preferred associated alpha workflow. The output format you use also matter.

Comment: The padding will be back when the image gets pre-divided upon saving as PNG. You just can't see it because Blender's viewer expects an associated alpha buffer.

Comment: I couldn't export with unassociated alpha from AE, that's why I have to separate sequences I want to join into one sequence with unassociated alpha. A solution to export as unassociated from AE would also work.

Comment: @gez Nope, the padding gets removed, not visible also after export. (I mean padding that is around 100 pixels, not the couple pixel alpha padding)

Comment: Sure. the only padding you'll get is from semi-transparent alpha. But since you want to preserve RGB intact, then use the method described in my answer. It won't look ok in the viewer, but the saved image will be fine and will preserve all RGB pixels.

Comment: Just tried it, both with 8 and 16 png - I don't get the RGB info back after exporting : ( Maybe will try some other formats.

Comment: Connecting the alpha directly or through a set-alpha node? Try saving with the "use alpha" checbox disabled.

Comment: With 'use-alpha' disabled I get no alpha and RGB info outside alpha gone. I also tried https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mlmwkn6w5q9epn6/shot_170905_213854.png and export to RGBA tga, but then alpha channel is just white : /

Comment: No, wait. you have to connect the alpha channel to the alpha socket too.
Also get rid of that separate node. Why are you pulling the alpha from the red channel? Pull it from the image socket straight away

Comment: Ok, got it. I went back to after effects and found that it exports straight alpha correctly when you use format other than png (or I screw something up last time).

Comment: I pulled alpha from the red channel because I exported sequence meant for the alpha as RGB, so any channel would do (I chose red).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you try to achieve is extremely simple:
Just plug the RGB image to the Composite's node "Image" socket and plug the Alpha image to the alpha channel, and make sure you're saving to an unassociated alpha format, as PNG.
The same effect is achieved by just plugging a set alpha node and connect the output (Now RGBA with the new alpha assigned) to the Composite's "Image" socket.

Keep in mind that both methods will produce exactly what you want, but you won't be able to see it in the viewer, as Blender expects an associated buffer to display. The saved PNG will be fine.

That being said, it's important to remember that PNG and unassociated alpha are no the best choice for CG and VFX.
Associated alpha allows you to create composites where your transparent pixels can also be luminous, producing lighting effects that are absolutely impossible using unassociated (straight) alpha.
Preserving RGB is only useful when you want to do associated alpha compositing. It is completely useless with unassociated as the alpha over operation will make any pixel with alpha=0 disappear.

Comment: Adding to that, After Effects can be used for this as well - it can export tga sequences with straight (or premultiplied) alpha.

Comment: But it's internal pipe is still unassociated, which mangles some associated files with luminscent transparent pixels. In this case it won't make any difference for you, but it's goog to keep that in mind when you're producing the source assets with an associated alpha program.